# jQuery UI Accordion - keeping elements closed while page loads

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I am using jQuery Accordion to group 5 different sections on my site. This works well, with one exception: during page load, the elements INSIDE the accordions are showing, resulting in a very ugly load experience. Could I have these elements hidden on window load by default?

I have tried all the options the manual and other related questions on here are providing me:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    active: false,
    heightStyle: "Content",
    autoheight: false,
    alwaysOpen: false,
    collapsible: true
});
```

I do not know how to explain the problem better. It is not dissimilar to the old FOUC issues we used to get.

The stripped down HTML for the accordion is as follows:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>To-do List</h3>
    <div>
        ...
    </div>

    <h3>Contacts</h3>
    <div>
        ...
    </div>

    <h3>Notifications</h3>
    <div>
        ...
    </div>

    <h3>Activities</h3>
    <div>
        ...
    </div>

    <h3>Time</h3>
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem you describe is known as a Flash of Unstyled Content, or FOUC. The best way to fix this is to set the initial state of the relevant elements using CSS, as this is applied as/before the DOM loads.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks - what would such CSS look like if the parent has ID #accordion? I tried `$('#accordion > div').hide()` but that  is not preventing this FOUC.

Comment: We can't answer that without seeing the relevant HTML

Comment: Updated the question with the stripped down HTML for the accordion. Thanks!

Comment: @KobusMyburgh you can use `#accordion { display: none; }` in CSS. This will render before the JavaScript is executed in browser. So the items will not show. Then in jQuery, you can `.show()` when ready.

Comment: @Twisty - thank you. Good suggestion. Client has for now opted to have a spash page instead, but tends to change his mind, so will implement this if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example based on the Demo: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

```js
$(function() {
  $("#accordion").accordion({
    active: false,
    heightStyle: "Content",
    autoheight: false,
    alwaysOpen: false,
    collapsible: true
  }).show();
});
```

```css
#accordion {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
      Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum
      a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
      Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
      Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam
      nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
      Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel est.
    </p>
    <p>
      Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Remember that `$(function(){})` is a short cut for when the page is `ready`, or `$(document).ready()`. This means that the CSS, which will load in the HTML first, will be rendered by the browser before the JavaScript / jQuery code is executed.

This is why the HTML structure appears and *then* Accordion is initialized. It's often very brief, and sometimes only noticeable if there is more content or the content takes more time to load; like if it contains rich media.

To address this, we "hide" the elements with CSS and then "show" them with jQuery. Yes, the CSS is still applied, yet the element's style will override it. You can also add a Class like `hidden`, with the same styling, and remove it when you're ready.

Comment: Thank you - this does work and answers the question.