# jQuery first click ignored?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have this piece of code used with jQuery UI

```
function ViewClient(RelationID) {
    console.log('entering');
    $('a[id^="contact_show"]').on('click', function (e) {
        console.log('clicking '+RelationID);
        ShowClientInfo(RelationID);
        $('#accordion').accordion({active: 2});
    });
}
```

The link the user clicks to do the action looks like this (and resides on panel 1 of the accordion):

```
<a href="#" id="contact_show_204" onclick="ViewClient(204);">View Client</a>
```

This should then close panel 1, and open panel 2.

The accordion is initialized as follows:

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    active: false,
    heightStyle: "Content",
    collapsible: true
});
```

When I click one of the IDs, the first click is always ignored (the correct accordion is not displayed). It only shows the correct accordion on the second and later clicks. The DOM is ready at the time I do the first click. I do not know what else to check. Any ideas?

*Edit:*

I have now added console.log for entering the function and clicking the element to the ViewClient() function, and what happens is that with every click, I do get the log message "entering", but the clicking only works on the second click onwards. What is strange though, is that it does not seem to "reset" the event:

```
entering

entering
clicking 204
clicking 206

entering
clicking 204
clicking 206
clicking 206

entering
clicking 204
clicking 206
clicking 206
clicking 206
```

Note that the second time I clicked, I clicked on a different ID (206). But it does the same thing if I clicked the original ID as well (204). I tried returning false and preventDefault(). It seems to me like a delayed DOM update?

Comment: You need to show much more code in a [mcve] for us to help

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: It's not normally something you would call on every click. You call it once when the page is loaded, then you can call accordion methods to show parts of it.

Comment: Thank you, @Barmar. The link the user would be clicking is in one accordion pane, and that must open an another pane in the same accordion, so I believe this is correct amplementation otherrwise.

Comment: @mplugian - thanks for the comment. That is the only JS used at that point of clicking a contact in the datatable listing. The link the user clicks is now added to the question.

Comment: @isherwood - you were right - ignore my comment above. I have removed the on click inside the function, and now it works. Please post your suggestion as an answer and I will accept it accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've assigned two click handlers to the same element(s). The one in your script and the one in the markup both fire on every click. You need to initialize your accordions separately, and you should call `ViewClient()` in the jQuery click handler.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you're using is for initializing an accordion. To change the settings of an existing accordion, you have to use the [`option`](https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-option) method (or `options` if you want to change multiple settings at once).

```
$("#accordion").accordion(); // initialize accordion
$('a[id^="contact_show"]').on('click', function (e) {
    ShowClientInfo(RelationID);
    $('#accordion').accordion("option", "active", 2); // change the active pane
});
```

Comment: Thank you - I changed to your  instruction, but it still ignores the first click on the link. Second link onwards works fine.

Comment: Did you initialize the accordion earlier?

Comment: I wonder if it is related to my other question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65961605/jquery-ui-accordion-keeping-elements-closed-while-page-loads - I reformatted the HTML code inside the accordions to see that all tags are properly closed, and they are - but the FOUC made me think that it could be broken HTML. Wondering if the FOUC mentioned here is related to the clicking anomaly - it is the same accordion.

Comment: Yes, the accordion is initialized earlier. I will put the way it is initialized in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, Barmar! The issue is now resolved by @isherwood's answer.